# How to share file across views in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a multi step file upload using symfony2.

The first screen allows users to upload a CSV file.

The second screen allows users to map a database column to a CSV column.

I have two methods in my controller, one for each screen.

file_upload => First screen

match_csv => Second Screen

Inside the file_upload method, I have the following code:

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('match_csv', 
                        array(
                               'accountId' => $accountId,
                               'projectId' => $projectId,
                               'file' => base64_encode( $file->getPathname() )
                              )
                         ), 301);
```

and in my `match_csv` method, I have the following code:

```
    $file = base64_decode($file);
    $csvFile = new \SplFileObject( $file );
    $csvFile->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
```

**My problem is:**

When I switch views from `file_upload` to `match_csv`, the server returns an error stating that the file no longer exists.

It is of my understanding that PHP deletes temp files as soon as a script's execution stops. Hence, when I switch views in symfony2 the file_upload method stops and the file is deleted.

**My questions is/are:**

Is there a better alternative to share an uploaded file across views?

Is it a good idea to write a temporary file myself, and then delete it right after I stopped using it so that Symfony2/PHP do not delete it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store the file name in the url, it's a security risk. Use the session for that.

1. I would do it like this: upload the file to a temporary area and
   store the path you moved it to in the session.
2. Then, in your second method, get the path from the session, do the
   parsing and then remove the file. That's it.

Comment: The filename in the url was for the demonstration purposes only really, I left it like that the last time I touched my code before moving the filename from the session to the URL.